# Implementing Floor Division on secp256k1 Elliptic Curve in Python

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, secp256k1

I understand that the `//` operator is used for floor division in regular arithmetic

```
result = 7 // 3  # This will result in 2
```

but how can I adapt this to work with the specific mathematical operations involved in secp256k1?

Could someone provide guidance or a code snippet illustrating how to perform floor division on secp256k1 elliptic curve in Python?

Comment: Are you looking for something that, given xG, will give you (x//3)G?  If so, well, we hope that you can't (because such an operation allows you to break ECC...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, us have a public base point $G$ on the curve $E$, and let us have a public key $P$ with a related secret key $k$ with $P = [k]G$.

**Discrete Logarithm**

Finding $k$ given $G$ and $P$ and curve parameters is called the **Discrete Logarithm Problem** (DLP)  on the curve. In general, if there is no special structure of the curve this is a hard problem and the best generic algorithms (Pollard's Rho) have $\sqrt{n}$ cost where $n$ is the number of the points on the curve.

**Division Floor Problem (DFP)**

Let's call this problem a Division Floor Problem (DFPx) that is given $[k]$ returns $[\lfloor k/x \rfloor]G$.

**Oracles**

We use Oracle/machine/program as a tool to investigate relations with other problems.

**DLP $\implies$ DFP**

If we have an oracle to solve discrete logarithm then we solve the DFP problem since we can get $k$ and simply use `//` and scalar multiplication to return the desired value. So, DLP is at least as hard as DFP.

**DFP2 $\implies$ DLP** :

Now, Let us have a DFP2 oracle given $[k]G$ that returns $[\lfloor k/2 \rfloor]G$. Now, we can use this oracle to break the Discrete Logarithms as follows

1. extracted = 0, step = 0
2. Ask oracle $P = [k]G$. Oracle returns $P' = [\lfloor k/2 \rfloor]G$
3. if $[2]P' = [k]G$ then we know that the last bit of $k$ is $0$
   else the last bit of $k$ is $1$
4. $\text{extracted} | (\text{last bit} \ll \text{step})$
5. Let $step = step + 1$
6. Let $P = P'$
7. if all bits of $k$ are not determined,

   set `k = k //2` and return step 2.

As we can see, **we break the Dlog easily as long as the Oracle's operation is not expensive.** So, DFP2 is at least as hard as DLP.

**DFP3 $\implies$ DLP** :

This is a little more complicated, instead, I'll give the gist of the idea

- Let $k = 18$ and we get $6$. We can notice this if $(3[\lfloor k/3 \rfloor])G = [k]G$
- let $k = 17$ and we get $5$. We know that it is not the previous case so we try $3\cdot5 +1$ and $3\cdot5 +2$ if any of them is $17$ then we find the key bits.

Of course, we don't get $6$ or $5$, I've used the numbers to indicate how we can use the equality to $[k]P$ to determine the bits.

Similar Oracles can be designed for $//4$ or $//5$... requiring a little more work.

**Complexity and better alternative for large $x$**

As [Poncho pointed out](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108672/implementing-floor-division-on-secp256k1-elliptic-curve-in-python/108674?noredirect=1#comment232840_108674), for small $x$'s the above algorithm can work very nicely, with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$. We can see that see that with $[k]G - [x\lfloor(k/x)\rfloor]G = [k \bmod x]G$. By using this equality, we can find $k \mod x$ in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$-time with BsGs or Pollard's rho. Of course, for small $x$ we do not bother to initiate BsGs or Pollard's rho, using direct calculation is faster. For large $x$'s below is faster.

The improvement for the large $x$ comes from the binary search. Instead of looking all, we use the mentioned trick is check for $0<i<x$ in binary case to see that;

$$\big[\lfloor{(k-i)/x}\rfloor\big]G == \big[\lfloor(k/x)\rfloor\big]G$$

With this, we can recover $\mathcal{O}(\log x)$ per digit $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful explanation! I'm curious about the idea of designing oracles for $//3$ or $//4$. Could you provide more details or steps on how one might programmatically implement these oracles?

Comment: @Favour a little extended the answer.To implement such oracle, you need to give the $k$ it

Comment: Actually, the operation $//x$ is polynomially equivalent to the discrete log problem for any $1 < x < n(1-\epsilon)$, where $n$ is the order of $G$...

Comment: @poncho what about $k+1$, in this case it will return $[0]P$, then we have to process from $1$ to $k$

Comment: @kelalaka: your algorithm works nicely for small $x$ (which can recover the digits base $x$ with $O(\sqrt{x})$ time per digit.  For larger $x$, you can rely on checking if $((k-i)//x G == k//xG - iG$; that'll tell you whether $k \bmod x \le i$; you use binary searching to determine $k \bmod x$ taking $O(\log x)$ time per digit

Comment: @kelalaka: sorry, I meant checking if $((k-i)//xG == k//xG$...

Comment: @kelalaka: Naah, that's not why your algorithm uses $O(\sqrt{x})$ time.  Instead, it effectively computes $kG - x(k//x)G = (k \bmod x)G$.  Given that you know $0 \le k \bmod x < x$, you can compute the discrete log of $(k \bmod x)G$, recovering the value of $k \bmod x$ in square-root time (say, by using Giant Step/Baby Step).  Of course, for tiny $x$, you don't need to bother with GSBS; for modest $x$ (say, $x \approx 2^{20}$), you would

Comment: @poncho thanks for your time.